# How to set column width in tableview in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have a table with two columns. I should set the width to 30% and 70%. The table is expandable but not columns. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If by "the table is expandable but not the columns", you mean the user should not be able to resize the columns, then call `setResizable(false);` on each column.

To keep the columns at the specified width relative to the entire table width, bind the `prefWidth` property of the columns.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableColumnResizePolicyTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Void> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Void, Void> col1 = new TableColumn<>("One");
        TableColumn<Void, Void> col2 = new TableColumn<>("Two");
        table.getColumns().add(col1);
        table.getColumns().add(col2);

        col1.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(0.3));
        col2.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(0.7));

        col1.setResizable(false);
        col2.setResizable(false);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bit sad that this can't be managed in FXML. Like setting a `widthWeight` or something.

Comment: @TrudleR I think you can do this in FXML, no? `<TableColumn prefWidth="${table.width * 0.3}" ... />`. Haven't tried it but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This sounds extremely interesting what you do there. But it looks like the tableColumn is not able to multiply within the FXML. :)

Comment: @TrudleR What do you mean "tableColum is not able to multiply"? I tested; it works fine. It is just an expression binding: please [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding).

Comment: I just started a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293438/how-to-give-tablecolumns-a-relative-width-in-fxml
Now I will read your link :) Thanks

Comment: @TrudleR Wait, what? You posted a question, and *now* you're going to read the documentation? You are supposed to do the research *before* posting the question....

Answer (score 21):

The `TableView`s [`columnResizePolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#columnResizePolicyProperty) is your friend:

If you set `TableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY)` all columns will be equally resized until the `TableView`s maximum width is reached.

Additionally you can write your own policy: The policy is just a `Callback` where `ResizeFeatures` is given as input from where you have access to the `TableColumn`.

Comment: I already have set that. The table is getting resized properly. But the problem is I'm not able to set the column width. And if I resize, it is showing another empty column at the end.

Comment: Then you should consider posting an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your problem.