# How to give TableColumns a relative width in FXML?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Is it possible to get a resizing TableView in FXML, where each columns resizes itself relatively?
I know it's possible in code, but I'm specifically looking for an FXML approach.

This is the current approach:

```
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <fx:define>
        <Double fx:id="tableViewWidth" fx:value="600"/>
    </fx:define>
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="expensesTableView" editable="true" prefWidth="${tableViewWidth}">
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
            </columnResizePolicy>
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="Title" prefWidth="${tableViewWidth * 3}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="title" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Category" prefWidth="${tableViewWidth * 3}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="category" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Period" prefWidth="${tableViewWidth * 2}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="period" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Value" prefWidth="${tableViewWidth * 2}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="value" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The multiply-part doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please fix the code in your question. Why are you trying to bind to a `Double` (which is not observable and never changes its value)? What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: @James_D The idea was to not multiply an integer with a comma-number, althought it wouldn't really matter. Which kind of observable value would I need for that to work? Becuase Integer property won't just work like that.
At the moment, of course, nothing happens. :/ The code I wrote is more an idea than an actual approach.

Comment: You linked a [comment section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428280/how-to-set-column-width-in-tableview-in-javafx/28439105?noredirect=1#comment65920465_28439105) that shows how to do it. Why don't you do it that way? I have no idea what "Integer property won't just work like that" means. And please fix your code; everything is duplicated and you have missing `}` all over the place, etc.

Comment: @James_D I fixed the code. Messed it up initially somehow. :)

Comment: I still don't understand why you didn't try it the way I suggested in the comments to the previous question, especially as you just accepted an answer that is completely identical to that. Why clutter up this site with unnecessary duplication?

Comment: @James_D Other people will have the same problem and they may be able to find it. The accepted answer was what I tried first, but I didn't think about the constrained_resize_policy and searched the error somewhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the resize policy and also bind to the width of the `TableView` instead to some double constant.

Furthermore some of the expressions used for the binding are syntactically wrong...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="expensesTableView" editable="true" prefWidth="600">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="Title" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.3}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="title" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Category" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.3}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="category" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Period" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.2}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="period" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Value" prefWidth="${expensesTableView.width*0.2}">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="value" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: thx a lot for your answer! I tried out this solution, but the `.width` is not recognized. I tried out `.predWidth` as well, since this property is explicitly set in my tableview. It's not recognized either, tho. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have just realized: Actually, the `.width` property is recognized. The multiplication is not recognized: I can set `"<TableColumn prefWidth=${expensesTableView.width}>"` but I cannot set `"<TableColumn prefWidth=${expensesTableView.width*0.3}>"`. I have set the constraint policy to unconstraint.

Comment: allright, last comment: It seems this is a problem with IntelliJ. The code works fine and does not throw any errors. But Idea marks mathematical expressions inside expression bindings as an error. It's a bit annoying.