# TableView setting column width percentage, arbitary number

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to set a tableview's column width with a percentage value.

I started from here: [How to set column width in tableview in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428280)
 but this way even if I remove the insets it doesn't work properly.

Here is my code:

```
 private TableColumn<NetworkDrive, ?> createTableColumn(String columnName, String propertyName, String alignment,
                                                       double widthPercentage) {
    TableColumn<NetworkDrive, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
    tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(propertyName));
    tableColumn.setStyle(alignment);
    tableColumn.setReorderable(false);
    tableColumn.setResizable(false);
    tableColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(networkDriveTableView.widthProperty()
            .multiply(widthPercentage / 100.0)
            .subtract(((networkDriveTableView.getInsets().getLeft() + networkDriveTableView.getInsets().getRight()) / COLUMN_COUNT)));
    return tableColumn;
}
```

Output:
[image: badTable]

If I add a +0.7 to the subtract part:

```
.subtract(((networkDriveTableView.getInsets().getLeft() + networkDriveTableView.getInsets().getRight()) / COLUMN_COUNT) + 0.7));
```

It work perfectly, and I don't know why. 
Could someone explain this? Am I doing something wrong?

[image: goodTable]

The table insets are 10 for all. I have 3 column.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set column width in tableview in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428280/how-to-set-column-width-in-tableview-in-javafx)

Comment: @Sedrick I'm using that method but it does't work for me, even when I remove the insets.

Comment: I would first follow the `duplicate` exactly. Once you see that it is working, then make changes to fit your situation.

Comment: @Sedrick Even if I just use the code there I get the first picture I posted.

Comment: Seeing that in the `duplicate` that `col1.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(0.3));` takes a `Double`, you can easily alter these three numbers to show your columns accordingly. You seem to be making this harder than it should. If you got the first picture using the example, try reducing all your numbers by .01 until you get the column widths you need.

Comment: @Sedrick Seeing that I pass the percentage as an int (15,70,15 respectively) and divide them by 100.0 (which gives 0.15,0.70,0.15) they passed as a double to the multiply method. 
So I can't make a general solution and has to play with the numbers every time I add another column? I figured out that adding 0.7 to the subtract method makes it work, I'm just curious why do you even need that. What's that additional 2.1 value

Comment: Okay so inside your method try `widthPercentage = widthPercentage - 1` or `widthPercentage = widthPercentage - 1.3` before you pass it to the column binding. Since this is a double, you should be able to come up with a value that gets this right.

Comment: Create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I can explore deeper.