# JavaFX: Set every column minimum width

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to set every column minimum width to 100px. I prefer to use `tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);`

**Explanation**

> If you set TableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY) all columns will be equally resized until the TableViews maximum width is reached.

[Explanation from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28428779/9892631)

At the moment the width of each column is determined by the width of the `TableView`devided by the number of columns.

I tried to set every column the minimum width but that didn't work. I've also saw that people just created their own callback for the `setColumnResizePolicy` but I couldn't implement my idea of what should happen.

**MCVE**

```
public class MCVE extends Application {

    private Scene mainScene;
    private Stage mainStage;
    private Label filename;
    private VBox mainBox;

    private TableView<String> tableView;

    private Button open;
    private Button save;
    private Button neu;
    private Button settings;
    private Button table;
    private Button row;
    private Button column;
    private Button date;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        initButton();
        initTable();

        mainStage = new Stage();
        filename = new Label("Nr. 100 - Test Data (Applikation: TEST)");
        mainScene = new Scene(mainVBox(), 1200, 600);


        tableView.prefWidthProperty().bind(mainBox.widthProperty());
        tableView.prefHeightProperty().bind(mainBox.heightProperty());

        mainStage.setScene(mainScene);
        mainStage.show();
    }

    private GridPane mainGrid() {

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);

        gridPane.add(filename, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(buttonBox(), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(tableView, 0, 2);

        return gridPane;
    }

    private VBox buttonBox() {

        VBox buttonBox = new VBox();

        HBox firstRowBox = new HBox();
        HBox secRowBox = new HBox();

        firstRowBox.getChildren().addAll(open, save, neu, settings);
        firstRowBox.setSpacing(5);
        secRowBox.getChildren().addAll(table, row, column, date);
        secRowBox.setSpacing(5);

        buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(firstRowBox, secRowBox);
        buttonBox.setSpacing(5);
        buttonBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(mainBox.widthProperty());

        return buttonBox;
    }

    private VBox mainVBox() {

        mainBox = new VBox();

        mainBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(mainStage.widthProperty().multiply(0.8));

        mainBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10 ,10));
        mainBox.getChildren().add(mainGrid());

        return mainBox;
    }

    private void initButton() {

        open = new Button("Open");
        open.setPrefWidth(100);
        save = new Button("Save");
        save.setPrefWidth(100);
        neu = new Button("New");
        neu.setPrefWidth(100);
        settings = new Button("Settings");
        settings.setPrefWidth(100);
        table = new Button("Table");
        table.setPrefWidth(100);
        row = new Button("Row");
        row.setPrefWidth(100);
        column = new Button("Column");
        column.setPrefWidth(100);
        date = new Button("Date");
        date.setPrefWidth(100);
    }


    private TableView initTable() {
        tableView = new TableView<>();

        // Create column UserName (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<String, String> userNameCol //
            = new TableColumn<>("User Name");

        // Create column Email (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<String, String> emailCol//
            = new TableColumn<>("Email");

        // Create 2 sub column for FullName.
        TableColumn<String, String> firstNameCol //
            = new TableColumn<>("First Name");

        TableColumn<String, String> lastNameCol //
            = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");


        // Active Column
        TableColumn<String, Boolean> activeCol//
            = new TableColumn<>("Active");

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(userNameCol, emailCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, activeCol);

        for (int i = 0; tableView.getColumns().size() < i; i++){

            tableView.getColumns().get(i).setMinWidth(100);
        }

        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        return tableView;
    }
}
```

In the end I expect that after I load the file, the width of the column should still be the TableView width devided by the number of columns expect the width would be < 100px. In this case every width should be 100px and a scrollpane appears (ignores the scrollbar here).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: and why all the width bindings? Chances are, they are conflicting somewhere. In debugging layout issues it's typically a good idea to start with no external setting/binding of pref or any other size property and understand what happens naturally. Tweaking those natural sizes should be the second step.

Comment: @kleopatra as vl4d1m1r4 said was the only thing that didn't work was my for-loop. And thank you for tips and next time I'll make a correct mcve.

Comment: it is correct - as you can see by the fact that it is answerable, all fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint of min width is never set...

Just replace this:

```
 for (int i = 0; tableView.getColumns().size() < i; i++){
```

to this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getColumns().size(); i++) {
```

Or even better use `forEach`:

```
 tableView.getColumns().forEach(column -> column.setMinWidth(100));
```

Comment: Thank you. I just found it out a few minutes ago.