# TableColumn prefWidth

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a TableView in my code for which I am saving the index and width of each TableColumn when the application shuts down (values are saved to a Properties file). When I start the application again, I want to reset the index and width of each TableColumns back to what is was when the application was shut down.

```java
        // If all columns are known, reorder the columns and set the width
        if (allKnown) {
            ObservableList<TableColumn<T, ?>> columns = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            // Column order and width
            TableColumn<T, ?> column;
            for (int i = 0; i < colIndex.length; i++) {
                column = getOriginalColumns().get(colIndex[i]);
                column.setPrefWidth(colWidths[i]);
                columns.add(column);
            }
            getTableView().getColumns().setAll(columns);
        }
        getTableView().setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

Setting the index works correctly, the column is set in the correct location of the TableView. However, this does not work for the column's prefWidth (all columns are resizable). I have looked at different fora and the culprit seems to be the CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY. I want to keep that option, since the main screen of my application can be resized. If I use unconstrained, the width works, but then I loose the ability to auto-scale the TableView when the application's main window resizes.

Has anyone experienced the same and found a solution? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm .. _does not work for the column's prefWidth_ what do you expect, exactly? The snippet should start up with the prefs, provided the tableView (and  its parents up to a layout root/scene/stage) has the same width as at storage time. That said: best to provide a [mcve] so we can give it a look (might be a bug in fx, the constrained mode is .. ;)

Comment: okay, my expectation was wrong: the policy doesn't care about prefs but simply distributes the available width evenly across columns .. how weird is that ..

Comment: next round (of thinking loud ;) - for initial sizing it's similar to the old Swing resize code (minus caring about pref sizes): the new column size is `min + factor* (max - min)` with factor near to `tableWidth/(sum(all max))` which is the same for all columns ..  to achieve some bias on pref, you can (temporarily if needed) set each col max to a small multiple (3, 4, 5 .. experiment at bit) of its pref.

Comment: Maybe this helps you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28428779/11219989)

Comment: I have looked at the link that micpog90 provided, that doesn't help much, it just confirms what kleopatra already stated. I am ok with the distribution of the width by the constrained resize, but I just cannot understand why it doesn't take the preferred width into account. What I think should happen, is that the table's width is spread evenly across the columns which don't have there preferred width (and/or maximum width?) set.

Comment: it's a very simplistic resizePolicy (even documented as such ;) .. to improve and make it behave as you want, you can always write your own

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to initially set the minWidth instead of the prefWidth.  then a few pulses after showing the UI, fix the minWidth so column resizing works normally again.

Comment: Why the down vote?  As ugly as it is, this workaround solves the issue of restoring column widths when CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY is in effect.  As noted by kleopatra, the implementation does not pay attention to the preferred size.  It does however pay attention to the minimum size.  Short of changes to JavaFX, I'm not sure there is any better way to get the desired effect.

Comment: How ugly it may be, it solved the problem. I have wrapped the resetting of the minWidth in a Platform.runLater which does the business. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction!